# Ruby - How to DRY better this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, dry

Is there any DRYer way to write this method ? or is it better to keep it this way for better reader understanding ...

Each role has a list of authorised activities for a specific resource ( in this case Sheet) , a user may have multiple roles ( depending upon his company, his working group in the company, his function in the working group). This method is a sheet_policy, if among all roles , the current user can "index" sheets, the method returns true otherwise it returns false

```
   def index?
    # check if sheet#index is listed in current_user roles activities
    sheet_activities = []
    user.roles.each {|role| sheet_activities << role.activities["sheet"]}
    return false if sheet_activities.first.nil? # no authorized activities on Sheet
    sheet_activities.flatten.uniq!.include?("index")
  end
```

activities is a JSONB attribute of the Sheet record ...

```
create_table :roles do |t|
  t.string      :company, null: false, default: Settings.company.default.name
  t.string      :group
  t.string      :function
  t.jsonb       :activities, null: false, default: '{}'      
  t.timestamps  null: false
```

Seeding example :

```
   @role_accounting_employee = Role.create( group: "accounting", function: "employee")  # default company : "internal"
   @role_accounting_employee.activities.deep_merge!({sheet: %w(show index) })
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: It belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks a lot to both of view ... I'll do it